# How use custom upload directories in filesystem and url based on media type or category

Tags: uploads, media, sort, directory

How can i choose when uploading a file or more where i want the file to go?

Like i have 6 brochures and i want they go to `wp-content/upload/brochures/`

Other example is i have 20 images which 10 will be upload now, and i want they go to `wp-content/upload/sliders` and the others 10 i would later just by selecting the upload directory upload to that place...

Is that possible?

I wanted something like the [WordPress Real Media Library](https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-real-media-library-media-categories-folders/13155134) but apparently that plugin don't touch the URL nor the "filesystem"

I know the [Custom Upload Dir](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) Plugin but is some outdated...

The best would be something like these 2 plugins combined into one

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you search on [Github](https://github.com/) for a plugin that'll suit your needs. A quick search lead me to [wp-file-upload](http://www.pluginmirror.com/plugins/wp-file-upload/)